# How to save Id field of embedded object using Gorm (Mongo)

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I am developing Grails(Gorm) application using mondodb. I have domain class with embedded object inside.

```
class SomeEntity {
    static mapWith = "mongo"

    ObjectId id
    ...
    SomeEmbedded some
    ...
    static embedded = ['some']
```

Embedded class has String Id field which I am trying to set and save but I see that exactly field with name 'Id' is ignored for embedded object. *SomeEmbedded* is not in `domain` package

```
class SomeEmbedded {
    String id
    ...
}
```

Is it possible add some configuration/mapping to be able set and save Id field for embedded objects.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `grails.gorm.annotation.Entity` on SomeEmbedded will allow saving the SomeEmbedded with Id.

```
@Entity
class SomeEmbedded {
    String id
    ...
}
```